# CSS - Web Page has incorrect CSS version when viewed through Twitter

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile

I recently added different css files for viewing my website through Mobile devices or Desktop devices.  Below is a short sample of the CSS code used to alter the style for each device:

```
@media all {
  p{
font-size: 2.5em;
 }
```

---

So, through my iPhone, I get the proper style when I view my website through Safari.

Safari View:
[image: Safari View]

---

But When users click on the link to my website through Twitter on their phones, they receive the CSS rendered for non-mobile devices.

Twitter via Mobile View:
[image]

---

What CSS can I use in order to have the proper style applied to my webpage when viewing the mobile site via Twitter?

Comment: Show us the _incriminated_ CSS. You may need to add a meta for viewport to handle UIWebView viewer.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti  I am not familiar with incriminated CSS.  Please provide an example of uiwebview meta in an answer.

Comment: I mean: I suppose Twitter App is using UIWebView to display HTML content, I don't have an iPhone here to try but I guess it's only about different defaults (if any...) for viewport setting. Just show us the CSS you're using to select one layout or the other (with @media all I can't say which max-width you're using)

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti I am only using @ media all.  What CSS tag should I use to include uiwebview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching,  I've discovered the answer.  Add the following to the Head of your project:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```